# 2-d array alternate of map

Tags: c++

Below is my code....

i had use an map here..instead of map i want to use 2-d array .
user will enter command code say 50 and corresponding function will be called that is registered like

```
to_do_commands.registerCommand(50,get_status);
```

full code below

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <assert.h> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <map> 
#include <string> 
 using namespace std;


void ping(void) 
{ 
  cout << "ping command executed\n"; 
} 

void get_status()
{

cout<<"get status executed";
}

class ToDoCommands 
{ 
  public: 
    typedef void (*FunctionPtr)(); 
    typedef int Code; 

    void registerCommand(Code code,FunctionPtr); 
    void callFunction(Code); 

  private: 
    map<Code,FunctionPtr> func_map; 
}; 

void ToDoCommands::registerCommand(Code code,FunctionPtr func_ptr) 
{ 
  func_map[code] = func_ptr; 
} 

void ToDoCommands::callFunction(Code code) 
{ 
  assert(func_map.find(code)!=func_map.end()); 
  func_map[code](); 
} 

int main(int argc,char **argv) 
{ 
  ToDoCommands to_do_commands; 

 // to_do_commands.registerFunction(50,ping);
  to_do_commands.registerCommand(10,ping);
  to_do_commands.registerCommand(50,get_status);
  to_do_commands.callFunction(50); 

  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: _"i want to use 2-d array"_ what did you try ?

Comment: not going for map coz i want this code into dll..which vl be generic

Comment: @james: what does using a `std::map` have to do with the code being a .DLL or .EXE?? IMHO that makes not the slightest bit of difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid any STL-dependence in you header file, you could use the [PIMPL idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) and use anything you want in your implementation file (e.g. std::map).

It could look like this:

```
// ToDoCommands.h

class ToDoCommands
{
public:
  typedef void(*FunctionPtr)();
  typedef int Code;

  ToDoCommands();
  ~ToDoCommands();

  void registerCommand(Code code, FunctionPtr fptr);
  void callFunction(Code code) const;
protected:
private:
  ToDoCommands(ToDoCommands const &); // do not copy
  ToDoCommands & operator=(ToDoCommands const &); // do not assign

  class ToDoCommandsImpl;
  ToDoCommandsImpl * m_pimpl;
};

// ToDoCommands.cpp

#include "ToDoCommands.h"

#include <map>

class ToDoCommands::ToDoCommandsImpl
{
public:
  void registerCommand(Code code, FunctionPtr fptr)
  {
    m_map[code] = fptr;
  }

  void callFunction(Code code) const
  {
    std::map<Code, FunctionPtr>::const_iterator iter = m_map.find(code);
    iter->second();
  }

protected:
private:
  std::map<Code, FunctionPtr> m_map;
};

ToDoCommands::ToDoCommands()
: m_pimpl(new ToDoCommandsImpl())
{ }

ToDoCommands::~ToDoCommands()
{
  delete m_pimpl;
}

void ToDoCommands::registerCommand(Code code, FunctionPtr fptr)
{
  m_pimpl->registerCommand(code, fptr);
}

void ToDoCommands::callFunction(Code code) const
{
  m_pimpl->callFunction(code);
}
```

I have disallowed copying and assignment of the class for simplicity, you can add those methods if you really need them.

Comment: nice...how can i implement this same via array?

Comment: Why do you want to use an array? I speculated that you wanted to restrict the use of STL-containers in a class interface that is exported by a dll and thus proposed the pimplified interface. If you want to implement a dictionary using only tables, you need three of them iirc (cf. relational databases)